# Quantile threshold/filter within pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, split-apply-combine

I have one categorical variable and two numeric cols:

```
np.random.seed(123)    
df = pd.DataFrame({'group' : ['a']*10+['b']*10,
                   'var1' : np.random.randn(20),
                   'var2' : np.random.randint(10,size=20)})
```

I want to find, by `group`, the mean of `var1` after filtering to constrict `df` to the top-quartile `var2` values *by group*.  That is, the threshold for each group would be:

```
thresh = df.groupby('group')['var2'].quantile(0.75)
```

Here's a loopy demonstration of what I want to end up with:

```
for group, frame in df.groupby('group'):
    print(frame[frame.var2 >= frame.var2.quantile(0.75)].var1.mean())
# -1.4713362407192072
# 0.15512098976530683
```

The result should be a DataFrame with (`group`, `var`) columns or a Series indexed by `group`.  I believe the solution may involve `.transform`/`.apply` but am stuck there.

Comment: You want a dataframe of the group var and the calucated mean or want to create a new column with that value transformed

Comment: @Bharathshetty new object rather than new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @Bharathshetty's answer but making the function a little more flexible rather than incorporating it to a lambda:

```
def thresh_filter(obj, sort_var, tgt_var, q=0.75, stat='mean'):
    thresh = obj[sort_var].quantile(q=q)
    return getattr(obj[obj[sort_var] >= thresh][tgt_var], stat)()

print(df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: thresh_filter(x, 'var2', 'var1')))
group
a   -1.47134
b    0.15512
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for this ?

```
new = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x : \
          x[x.var2>=x.var2.quantile(0.75)] \
          .var1.mean()).to_frame()
```

```
             0
group          
a     -1.471336
b      0.155121
```